# Added CAD file to ArcMap, annotations that are present in AutoCAD showing up as points in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, autocad

So I added this cad file to my map using the add data button and everything showed up, except for these texts that belong to the lines. The text itself showed up as points[image]

The annotation layer transferred over no problem but these text values are separate from that annotation layer. The person that made the AutoCAD map only made these details available from what I found in the 'value' column in the attribute editor. From what I could tell, these values did not make it to any of my attribute tables in ArcMap. What would be the best way to migrate that data over?[image]